# Better way to use lots of variables C# Unity

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, int

I am working on a game at the moment in Unity, it is a 2D Based game with certain components in 3D. It is a Business Tycoon Game. So I'm using C# for my scripts and I currently have different staff types and need 3 variables for each staff type. XStaffTotal, XStaffFree, XStaffUsed and finally TotalStaff Which is the Sum of all XStaffTotal Variables. My question is what would be a good or the best way to use the variables. This is what I chose first, I think there is a better way but I can not figure it out.

```
public int TotalStaff;
public int LaborStaffFree;
public int LaborStaffUsed;
public int TotalLaborStaff;
public int RnDStaffFree;
public int RnDStaffUsed;
public int TotalRnDStaff;
public int AccountingStaffFree;
public int AccountingStaffUsed;
public int TotalAccountingStaff;
public int TechnicStaffFree;
public int TechnicStaffUsed;
public int TotalTechnicStaff;
public int SalesStaffFree;
public int SalesStaffUsed;
public int TotalSalesStaff;
public int MarketStaffFree;
public int MarketStaffUsed;
public int TotalMarketStaff;
```

*Edit*

More context coming up.
So basically I have 9 Buttons, Each time you click on one of the buttons, be it Hire Labor or Hire RnD it will +1 to the respective XStaffFree, so if I click Hire Labor.

`LaborStaffFree += 1;`

Then when you undertake a project in the game which requires staff to be assigned say researching motherboards, The project will have a set int of required staff, so

```
LaborStaffUsed += ProjectManager.requiredstaff;
LaborStaffFree -= LaborStaffUsed;
```

With ProjectManager being another c# script and requiredstaff being the aforementioned int.

PS. This is all in Unity

Comment: Why not create a structure for each type? *(e.g. LabourStaff {Free, Used, Total} )*

Comment: Hard to suggest a better, with out knowing what exactly all these properties are for and how you use them etc.. Maybe share little more of the context with us.

Comment: "I currently have different staff types and need 3 variables for each staff type." -- sounds like it's time to go OOP and introduce a `Staff` interface with concrete implementations :)

Comment: @stickybit More Context Provided

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by creating some classes and structs.
For example in your case, first create a simple struct for staff info:

```
public struct StaffInfo
{
     public int StaffFree;
     public int StaffUsed;
     public int TotalStaff;
}
```

And then use a class or struct that contains different property of StaffInfo type.

```
public class Staffs
{
      public StaffInfo LaborStaff {get;set;}
      public StaffInfo RnDStaff {get;set;}
      public StaffInfo AccountingStaff {get;set;}
      public StaffInfo TechnicStaff {get;set;}
      public StaffInfo SalesStaff {get;set;}
      public StaffInfo MarketStaff {get;set;}
      public int TotalStaff {get;set;}
}
```

And if TotalStaff is always equalled to used + free you can use read-only property with getter only.

```
public int TotalStaff => StaffFree + StaffUsed;
```